# how to validate GCM registration IDs?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using GCM to push notification for apps that have multiple registration ids(due to uninstall/reinstall the app) in our database, thus they are receiving the notification message multiple times.
Is there anyway we can validate or recover those tokens with REST GCM API?
Please note that i'm avoiding to use canonical_ids pushNotification response method as we do not want our clients to receive multiple notifiation.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: By validate, you mean by testing if the request will be successful, right? If so, have you considered using the `dry_run` [optional payload parameter](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json)?

Comment: By validate I mean to test if two or more registration ids belongs to the same app, if so we need to delete all those duplicated ids to avoid multiple  notification for same app.

Comment: Hmm. Isn't that what [canonical_ids](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/registration#canonical-ids) are for?

Comment: Yes but I was looking if there is another way how to handle this.
canonical_ids would be difficult for us to deal with in our situation as the platform we use is not returning the whole response we need from GCM.

Comment: I see. That was not mentioned in your post originally, so it was a little confusing. What I find odd is that you said you weren't receiving the wgole response..